# A proof of $\sum\limits_{d|n} \sigma(d) = n \sum\limits_{d|n} {\tau(d) \over d}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, divisor-counting-function

I'm trying to proof the following statement:

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and the $\sum$ are on the divisors $d$ of $n$.  Show that
$$\sum\limits_{d|n} \sigma(d) = n \sum\limits_{d|n} {\tau(d) \over d}.$$

I arrive to a point where I have a product of polynomials and I can't simply find a way to reorder the factors in order to resemble some kind of useful structure for this problem. Any suggestions?

---

EDIT: due to unsuscribe of **user593746**, I can't ask delucidation, so I reopen the question because I wish to have detailed delucidation on the passages on the first row of his good proof (summatory index manipulations and t outside the first sum):

> We have $$\sum_{d\mid n}\sigma(d)=\sum_{d\mid n}\sum_{t\mid d}t=\sum_{t\mid n}\sum_{k\mid \frac{n}{t}}t=\sum_{t\mid n}t\sum_{k\mid \frac{n}t}1,$$
>   where $k=\frac{d}{t}$.  So
>   $$\sum_{d\mid n}\sigma(d)=\sum_{t\mid n}t\tau\left(\frac{n}t\right)=\sum_{\delta \mid n}\frac{n}{\delta}\tau(\delta)=n\sum_{\delta\mid n}\frac{\tau(\delta)}{\delta},$$
>   where $\delta =\frac{n}{t}$.

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1948422/the-sigma-function-sum-of-divisors-multiplicative-proof

Comment: The sums express two different ways to count the sum of how many divisors $c\mid n$ each divisor $d\mid n$ divides.

Comment: Hey, do you remember user593746's nickname before he/she unsubscribe? Is it "Zvi"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here  is a derivation with some intermediate  steps which might be helpful.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{d\mid   n}\sigma(d)}&=\sum_{d\mid n}\sum_{t\mid d}t\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{{t\mid d\mid n}\atop{t,d\geq 1}}t\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{{t \mid tk \mid n}\atop{t,k\geq 1}}t\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{{t \mid n,k \mid \frac{n}{t}}\atop{t,k\geq 1}}t\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{t \mid n}t\sum_{k \mid \frac{n}{t}}1}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the definition of the divisor function $\sigma(d)=\sum_{t| d}t$.
- In (2) we write the index region somewhat more compactly. This does not change the sum, as it is only a rearrangement of  the summands.
- In (3) we use $t|d  \Longleftrightarrow  \exists k\geq 1 :  tk=d$, assuming $t,d,k$ are positive integers.
- In (4) we use the transitivity of the $|$ operator: $t| d| n\Longrightarrow t|n$ and we also use $t \cdot k| n\Longleftrightarrow t | \frac{n}{k}$.
- In (5) we rearrange the summands again by summing at first over $t| n$. We also factor out $t$  from  the  inner  sum, since $t$ does not  depend on the index  variable  $k$.

> **[Add-on 2019-01-17]:** A derivation using Dirichlet convolution due to OPs comment.
>
> Taking the unit-function $u(n)=1$ for all  $n$ and the function $N(n)=n$ for all $n$ we have 
>   \begin{align*}
> \tau(n)&=\sum_{d|n}1=(u\star u)(n)\\
> \sigma(n)&=\sum_{d|n}d=(u\star N)(n)
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{d|n}\sigma(d)}&=(\sigma  \star u)(n)\\
> &=((u\star N)\star u)(n)\\
> &=(u\star(N \star u))(n)\\
> &=(u\star (u\star N))(n)\\
> &=((u\star u) \star N)(n)\\
> &=(\tau \star N)(n)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{d|n}\tau(d)\frac{n}{d}}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

Comment: Thank you for this precise explanation; one thing, the term $t$ can be carried out of the fist sum according to some kind of properties or constraint?

Comment: @Alessar: You're welcome and you're right, we can factor out $t$ since it does not depend on the index of the inner sum. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Sheuer, one curious question; this kind of derivation in this proof can be done only using Dirichlet convolutions?

Comment: @Alessar: Many thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty. I've added a derivation based upon Dirichlet convolution.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Wish I could give 100 times that bounty!

Answer (score 3):

We have $$\sum_{d\mid n}\sigma(d)=\sum_{d\mid n}\sum_{t\mid d}t=\sum_{t\mid n}\sum_{k\mid \frac{n}{t}}t=\sum_{t\mid n}t\sum_{k\mid \frac{n}t}1,$$
where $k=\frac{d}{t}$.  So
$$\sum_{d\mid n}\sigma(d)=\sum_{t\mid n}t\tau\left(\frac{n}t\right)=\sum_{\delta \mid n}\frac{n}{\delta}\tau(\delta)=n\sum_{\delta\mid n}\frac{\tau(\delta)}{\delta},$$
where $\delta =\frac{n}{t}$.

Comment: In the final result $\delta$ has the same exact meaning of $d$, identify the same divisors, right?

Comment: Yep.  I used a different variable because I wanted to define $\delta=\frac{n}{t}$, which could be confusing if I say $d=\frac{n}{t}$, since $d$ is used in $k=\frac{d}{t}$ already.  But then, which ever variables you are using as the indices of summation don't really matter.

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for the very good answer!